# How does one make vodka from potatoes

Tags: mash, vodka

I ask this as a Russian born person of which would like to show off to friends and family. As a Russian born US citizen who occasionally gets playfully teased about our stereotypes, I would like to prove to them how stereotypical I can be.

Comment: Do you have distillation experience?

Comment: No I do not have any experience in brewing in general much less distillation, but I would be open to learning.

Comment: Also is it legal to distil where you are? A very important question.

Comment: From what I just looked up it seems to be legal but I need a license. I'm in the VA

Answer (score 5):

You could start with [this question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/23755/converting-potato-starch-in-to-sugars-for-brewing) from this forum to know how to turn potatoes into a sugary solution fit for fermentation.

Mind you, mashing not only means to mush the potatoes, but to add crushed barley malt and water. The crushed barley malt enzymes will turn the potato starches into sugars. Click on the tag "mash" to get more information.

However, after the fermentation process, vodka needs distilling, and that is a very specific theme, more subject to different laws, I suppose differing from state to state in the US, and also differing from country to country. And talking about distilling on HB SE seems to still be not generally accepted.

Comment: I accept talk about distillation, so long as there is some talk of mashing, fermenting etc... Pure distillation questions should probably be asked on Chemistry or Engineering SE. As they will have far more experience than most of us. Saying that I did make a 400l batch of Gin last year, with hops in :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Mr_road!